# Certificates and keys associated with your Azure ACS 2.0 Namespace(s) are about to expire

Tags: azure, acs

I received an e-mail from Azure Team a few days ago stating:

> Our records indicate that your subscription includes an Azure Access
>   Control Service (ACS) 2.0 Namespace.
>
> We are writing to inform you that certificates or keys related to your
>   namespace(s) are about to expire between July 15, 2014 – November 15,
>   2014. Please find below the namespace(s) for which certificates and keys need to be updated.    xxxACS, dev-sb, live-sb, uat-sb

I followed the instructions and when trying to check the status of these certificates inside the ACS Management Portal I get:

> Service Namespace certificates and keys are automatically managed for
>   this namespace

I found an old thread on MSDN [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/f97bdc09-01dc-4114-bdc2-d26531964028/certificate-and-key-expiration-information-regarding-your-access-control-service-acs-20-namespace?forum=windowsazuredata) which states this email is due to an error and should be ignored, but as it regards a live environment I would like a confirmation on this.

Comment: Recommend opening a support ticket to validate your assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I received a confirmation from Microsoft that this was indeed erroneously sent.

Original message below:

> Earlier this month, you may have erroneously received an expiration notice associated with your ACS 2.0 Namespace(s) certificates. These certificates are managed by Microsoft Azure and there is no action required by you.
>
> We may have sent you an expiration notice that incorrectly identified 
>   certificate(s) created by Service Bus/Cache Service and managed by
>   Azure as customer-managed certificates. Contrary to the original email
>   below, **there is no action required by you** at this time as these
>   certificates are managed by Azure. We have since changed our
>   identification process to avoid this in the future. We sincerely
>   apologize for any inconvenience caused.